# What does "qualified yes" exactly mean?

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning

I saw this phrase at quite a few places but never understood it. What does it mean when one says that "the answer is a qualified yes"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The person cannot say *yes* without "qualifying it". This means the speaker puts some condition on his/her *yes*. He/she cannot fully agree with a statement, or he/she can only say *yes* if some detail or explanation is added or made clear.

Example:

A: Will you help me with my homework tonight?

B: Yes,  if I have enough time after work.

B's *yes* is a "qualified yes" because there is a certain condition she places on it (*if she has enough time after work*).

Comment: You're welcome, in advance and now.